# node.js and javascript websockets communication

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I'm trying to get met webpage to communicate with node.js using websockets.
I've been trying for several hours now but simply don't know what is going wrong.

**server**

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    var handsShaked=false;

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        if(!handsShaked){
            data=(data+"").split("\r").join("").split("\n");
            var key=null;
            for(i in data){
                if(data[i].indexOf("Sec-WebSocket-Key:")===0)
                    key=data[i].split(":")[1].split(" ").join("");
            }

            var magic = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
            var sha = sha1(key+magic);
            var accept = new Buffer(sha).toString('base64');

            socket.write(
                "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"+
                "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"+
                "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"+
                "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "+accept+"\r\n"
            );

            handsShaked=true;
        }

        socket.write("test");
    });
});

server.listen(10666);
```

**client**

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:10666");
socket.onopen=function(){
    console.log('open');
    socket.send('Dit is een test');
}
socket.onmessage=function(msg){
    console.log('msg');
    alert(msg);
}
socket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('error');
    alert('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};
```

anyone knows why it is not working?

Comment: do you get any errors? what shows up in your console?

Comment: No errors. The socket will be opened and in node.js i can logwhen the user leaves because of the disconnection. None of the client side events is ever triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a final `\r\n` at the end of your handshake response

See the HTTP [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6)

```
   Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
                   *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
                    | response-header        ; Section 6.2
                    | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
                   CRLF
                   [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2
```

Your code is missing the `CRLF` after the response.

Once you get the handshake working, the line `socket.write("test");` won't work as you expect.  Websocket messages are [framed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) so you'll need additional code to read and write messages.